# problem with python function and np.vectorize

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Before I start to ask a question, I'm sorry not to be skilled in expressing my question in english and doing python...

To practice np.vectorize, I was writing some code.

```
def H(x):
if x == 0 : 
    return 0.5
elif x > 0:
    return 1
else :
    return 0
```

then, I define vH as vectorized function.

```
vH = np.vectorize(H)
```

and it works as I expect.

```
vH(0)
array(0.5)
```

however, when a input array has a negative number, it doesn't work for "zero".

```
a = np.array([ -1,  0. , 0, 1 ])
vH(a)
array([0, 0, 0, 1])              # I expect the result array([0, 0.5, 0.5, 1])
```

I try to find the reason and solution about this problem.
I really don't know why it happen...
Do I miss something???

please answer why it happen and how to fix it

thank you for reading this question!

Comment: Read what it says about the return value `dtype`, and the `otypes` parameter.  `vectorize` appears to be simple, but is trickier than it appears.  And it is never fast(er).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from your returns : you only return numbers as ints, so vectorize understands that you only work with ints, so when you give 1 and 0, your vH only gives ints. What you should do is return floats instead, and maybe convert them after if you want.

```
def H(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0.5
    elif x > 0:
        return 1.
    else :
        return 0.
vH = np.vectorize(H)
a = np.array([ -1,  0 , 0, 1 ])
vH(a)
```

For me, It returned :

```
array([0. , 0.5, 0.5, 1. ])
```